# Vuex Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I am trying to work with global variables with Vuex but also I do keep getting `undefined` error even I initialize `Vuex` using `Vue.use();`.

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'isAuth' of undefined`

store.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  isAuth: true,
});
```

main.js:

```
import store from './store/store';
....
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  router,
  render: h => h(App),
.......
```

I call `isAuth` to see its value like this: `this.$store.isAuth;` and this causes the `undefined` error.

I did initialize `Vuex` in `store.js`, but am still having the `undefined` error. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At a guess, this might work with what you're currently doing: `this.$store.state.isAuth` but I would do it like below.

I've not used the store in the way you have before but haven't had issues when using modules, try like this:

```
// authModule.js
const state = {
    isAuth: true
}

const getters = {
    getIsAuth (state) {
        return state.isAuth
    }
}

export default {
    state,
    getters
}
```

Then register it like so:

```
import authModule from './modules/authModule'
export default new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {
        authModule
    }
})
```

Then on your vue instance:

```
import {mapGetters} from 'vuex'

computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
        isAuth: 'getIsAuth'
    })
}
```

You can now access via `this.isAuth`. You can also access like: `this.$store.state.authModule.isAuth`

This is actually best practice according to their docs as it keeps things tidy when the project gets larger.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I no longer get the error but I still get `undefined` as the value of `isAuth`. Should I see the value or is it normal to see the value as `undefined`?

Comment: You should never see undefined, no. If you `console.log(this)` from your vue component, take a look and you should see `$store`. Does it have a value? You should be able to drill down into the state as well and see what value it has. That'd be a good place to start.

Comment: I modified a little bit more and I now am be able to see `$store` wherever I want. Thank you again for your time!

Comment: how do you this if you're using straight up js instead of .vue files?

Comment: @qodeninja Sorry, this isn't something I've done before so don't know. The Vuex website should have some information though.

Comment: @webnoob Maybe you can help me. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52529345/how-can-i-solve-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-get-of-undefined-in